# AWS ECR docker login succeeded, but can not pull/push (root user IAM does not work either). Same config works on another host

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr

**Task**: pull and push images to the AWS ECR (Private)

**Status**: works from one Ubuntu 20 host, does not work from another Ubuntu 20 host

**Briefly**: I have IAM and I am able to both push and pull from a working Ubuntu 20 host. There is another host, I tried both IAM and I even created a pair of credentials for root user, still, no luck. I tried both `docker login` approach and `https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper`.

Works from `19.03.8`.
Does not work from `19.03.12`, updated to `Docker 20.10.5`, still does not work.

Full explanation.

### Using docker login

1. `docker login` (zeros in reality contain my acc id)

```
$ aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 000000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/username/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

2. `$ cat ~/.docker/config.json` (zeros in reality contain my acc id)

```
{
        "auths": {
                "000000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com": {
                        "auth": "QVd[REMOVED A LOT OF CHARACTERS]Q=="
                }
        }
}
```

3. `cat ~/.aws/credentials`

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=A......A
aws_secret_access_key=x.......Q
```

4. `docker pull` (note: (a) image exists (b) I can pull and push from first Ubuntu (c) I replaced the credentials with the root user credentials for the testing purposes; same thing happens with the regular user creds)

```
$ docker pull 000000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/imagename:latest
Error response from daemon: pull access denied
for 000000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/imagename:latest, 
repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: User: arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root is not authorized to perform:ecr:BatchGetImage on resource: arn:aws:ecr:us-east-2:000000000000:repository/imagename
```

### Using aws-ecr-helper

1. `$ cat ~/.docker/config.json`

```
{
    "credsStore": "ecr-login"
}
```

2. `$cat ~/.ect/cache.json`

```
$ cat cache.json
{
  "Registries": {
    "us-east-2-Q[REMOVED]s+EJ+-000000000000": {
      "AuthorizationToken": "QV[REMOVED LOTS OF CHARACTERS]0=",
      "RequestedAt": "2021-03-07T12:26:37.65116332+01:00",
      "ExpiresAt": "2021-03-07T23:26:37.605Z",
      "ProxyEndpoint": "https://000000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com",
      "Service": "ecr"
    }
  },
  "Version": "1.0"
}
```

3. `docker pull`

```
$ docker pull 000000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/imagename:latest
Error response from daemon: pull access denied
for 000000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/imagename:latest, 
repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: User: arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root is not authorized to perform:
ecr:BatchGetImage on resource: arn:aws:ecr:us-east-2:000000000000:repository/imagename
```

Just to clarify. Exactly same config with both regular user AND with root works on another host. Please advise where to go next. Thank you.

**UPDATED.** Both working and not working hosts are outside of the AWS Ecosystem.

**UPDATED #2.**
I enabled CloudTrail logs, which allow me to see the requests from Amazon perspective.
So basically I am doing exactly the same thing from both computers. At the same time I receive the result from the first one and I get access denied from the second one.
Basically this means that both requests reach AWS, question is, why the second desktop does not have an access.

## Log after connecting from the desktop, which works

(000000000000 is my acc id)

```
eventVersion    "1.08"
userIdentity    
type    "Root"
principalId "000000000000"
arn "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root"
accountId   "000000000000"
accessKeyId "A[DELETED]Q"
sessionContext  
sessionIssuer   {}
webIdFederationData {}
attributes  
mfaAuthenticated    "false"
creationDate    "2021-03-07T19:19:57Z"
invokedBy   "AWS Internal"
eventTime   "2021-03-07T19:20:03Z"
eventSource "ecr.amazonaws.com"
eventName   "BatchGetImage"
awsRegion   "us-east-2"
sourceIPAddress "AWS Internal"
userAgent   "AWS Internal"
requestParameters   
registryId  "000000000000"
repositoryName  "imagename"
imageIds    
0   
imageTag    "latest"
acceptedMediaTypes  
0   "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json"
1   "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json"
2   "application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json"
3   "application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json"
4   "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+prettyjws"
5   "application/json"
responseElements    null
requestID   "e514746b[DELETED]"
eventID "3e6db33d[DELETED]"
readOnly    true
resources   
0   
accountId   "000000000000"
ARN "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-2:000000000000:repository/imagename"
eventType   "AwsApiCall"
managementEvent true
eventCategory   "Management"
recipientAccountId  "000000000000"
```

## And at the same time
Log after connecting from the desktop, which is always denied

```
eventVersion    "1.08"
userIdentity    
type    "Root"
principalId "000000000000"
arn "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root"
accountId   "000000000000"
accessKeyId "A[DELETED]A"
sessionContext  
sessionIssuer   {}
webIdFederationData {}
attributes  
mfaAuthenticated    "false"
creationDate    "2021-03-07T17:30:12Z"
invokedBy   "AWS Internal"
eventTime   "2021-03-07T19:02:50Z"
eventSource "ecr.amazonaws.com"
eventName   "BatchGetImage"
awsRegion   "us-east-2"
sourceIPAddress "AWS Internal"
userAgent   "AWS Internal"
errorCode   "AccessDenied"
errorMessage    "User: arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root is not authorized to perform: ecr:BatchGetImage on resource: arn:aws:ecr:us-east-2:000000000000:repository/imagename"
requestParameters   null
responseElements    null
requestID   "371354a8[DELETED]"
eventID "2f9f0310[DELETED]"
readOnly    true
eventType   "AwsApiCall"
managementEvent true
eventCategory   "Management"
recipientAccountId  "000000000000"
```

Note for those who thinks about credentials, the access key you see under those logs is not the access key of the user. Those access keys are different on each request (Even each request from the working desktop has different access key).

**UPDATED #3**. I checked from 3rd Ubuntu 17 host with Docker 18 and fresh aws cli, it works. So this is definitely something about the setup, docker or aws cli, not about the ECR itself.

**UPDATED #4**. I made a test with shell proxies (tinyproxy + SSH tunnel) and tests to eliminate some kind of shadow IP ban possibility. So basically:

- working host keeps working through the proxy based on the non-working host and
- non-working host keeps failing through the proxy based on the working host
  Which means there is something with the docker on specific host, but removing and installing docker again does not solve it.

Comment: Accesskey in your logs in both ends differently? `accessKeyId "A[DELETED]A"` and `accessKeyId "A[DELETED]Q"`?

Comment: Thanks. I checked that. Those are not the real keys. They are different for each operation, and they do not match those which I provide to AWS, they are kind of internal keys. So even 2 different successfull pulls from the 'working' machine contain different keys in the logs (and neither of them match my real key).

Comment: Check if any proxies configured on the system where is not working? You should look for environment variables like HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY and also check using curl on https://www.google.com to make sure certs are coming back fine. Another issue that can happen is a date/time in future or too much in past. A wrong timezone or wrong UTC time configured on the machine can also cause that. Try running `hwclock -w --localtime` and see if that helps

Answer (score 1):

As you confirm that it is not an IAM role issue, You can receive this error due to one of the following issues:

**Your launch type doesn't have access to the Amazon ECR endpoint.**

1. If your host is in a private subnet then confirm that your subnet has a route to a NAT gateway in the route table.
2. If your host is in a public subnet, then confirm that the instance has a public IP address.
3. If you're using AWS PrivateLink for Amazon ECR, then confirm that the security group, associated with the interface VPC endpoints for Amazon ECR,allows inbound traffic over HTTPS (port 443) from within the security group of your VPC CIDR or your host security group.
4. Confirm that the security group attached to your host allows outbound access for the following: HTTPS on port 443, DNS (UDP and TCP) on port 53, and your subnet's network access control list (network ACL).

**Your Amazon ECR repository policy restricts access to repository images.**
The following repository policy example allows IAM users to push and pull images:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowPushPull",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/push-pull-user-1",
          "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/push-pull-user-2"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:PutImage",
        "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
        "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
        "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should have clarified, that both working and not working hosts are outside the AWS Ecosystem. I updated the question with that information as well.

Comment: Could you check the ECR repository policy, if there is any condition about the source ip address?

Comment: As far as I understand, root user can access anything.
Still, the policy for the user (which I also tried to login with) contains the following:
```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ecr:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}```